# How to properly validate date field in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am very new to Django forms and I'm trying to make a very simple form to select a `from` and `to` dates to filter out some data. I don't wan't the `to` date to be later than today's date.
I'm having a hard time understanding why when `clean_to_date` fails i.e., the `to` date is later than Today, the `cleaned_data` dict only has a `from_data`.

```
class DateSelect(forms.Form):
    from_date = forms.DateTimeField(
                    label='From:',
                    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
                    required=False)

    to_date = forms.DateTimeField(
                    label='To:', 
                    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
                    required=False)


    def clean_to_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['to_date']

        if data != None and data > datetime.today():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                    """
                    \'to\' date cannot be later than today.
                    """)
```

This is my piece of code in the html template so when I hit OK I just want it to refresh and display the filtered data.

```
<form action="/admin/report/latest-uploads/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

BTW, I have read already Django's documentation on Form and field validations but I'm still a bit confused.

`views.py`

```
def latest_uploads(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DateSelect(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            from_date = form.cleaned_data['from_date']
            to_date = form.cleaned_data['to_date']

            #some if function calls here

            context = {...
                       'from': form}
    
            return render(request, 'health_report/latest-uploads.html', context)

    else:
        form = DateSelect(request.GET)

        # function here

        context = {...,
                   'form': form}

        return render(request, 'health_report/latest-uploads.html', context)
```

Comment: please share your view function

Comment: @PruthviBarot just edited. I was avoiding having a too long post for a small question.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you're checking for `None` but it is possible to make it `required=True` in the form definition.
The very important in the cleaning process, that every def clean_() function needs to return a cleaned value or the same value (if it's OK).

[Docs is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute):

> ```
>     # Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data, even if
>     # this method didn't change it.
> ```

So back to your code:

```
def clean_to_date(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['to_date']
    if data > timezone.now().date():
        raise forms.ValidationError("'to' date cannot be later than today.")
    return data
```

**UPD:**
Also, you have to use Timezone instead of DateTime.
`from django.utils import timezone`
Check the code, with `timezone.now().date()` replacement.

Comment: The only reason I'm not using `required=True` is because it's possible to have from_date AND to_date empty because the filtering function that uses those dates have default values to filter for the last 7 days, if both fields are empty, for example.

Comment: aha! Ok, no problem, handle your cases with different values in the `if`-`elif`-`else` block, and always return cleaned_data ['field_nane'] 

Comment: Whenever I use `return data` in my `clean_to_date` and I have a `to_date` greater than today's date I get:
`to_date = self.cleaned_data['to_date']`
`KeyError: 'to_date'`

Comment: you can debug what you have in `self.cleaned_data` by printing it's value at the beginning of the `clean_to_date` function. What do you have there?

Comment: The thing is when I pass a `to_date` greater than today, and I have `return data` in my `clean_to_date` function I get and error as if the key `to_date` was dropped from the `form.cleaned_data` dict. I can't understand how to resolve that and how to make the `ValidationError` messages just show messages instead of breaking the requests.

Comment: when any exception raise your `if form.is_valid():` != `True`. So you don't have any handler for such a situation. You need to prepare an answer with errors to show for your user. You can use `form.errors` for details